# Sencha CMD build error com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I have just upgraded to sencha CMD 4.0.0.0 and started getting this error while building my package.

```
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Nipendo\Dev\WebApplication\packages\n-theme-classic\.sencha\package\build-impl.xml:184: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Nipendo\Dev\WebApplication\packages\n-theme-classic\.sencha\package\sass-impl.xml:94: com.sencha.exceptions.ExProcess: compass process exited with non-zero code : 1
     at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:444)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
     at com.sencha.ant.AntScript.execute(AntScript.java:127)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.execute(PluginManager.java:93)
     at com.sencha.command.plugin.PluginManager.executeReverseFirst(PluginManager.java:134)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:245)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.AppOrPackageEnvironment.execute(AppOrPackageEnvironment.java:394)
     at com.sencha.command.environment.BuildEnvironment.execute(BuildEnvironment.java:224)
     at com.sencha.command.pkg.BuildCommand.execute(BuildCommand.java:32)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at com.sencha.util.MethodInvoker$Arguments.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:174)
     at com.sencha.cli.Command.dispatch(Command.java:42)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.cli.Commands.dispatch(Commands.java:68)
     at com.sencha.command.Sencha.dispatch(Sencha.java:81)
```

Is there a workaround, does any body know what is that about??

Answer (score 10):

This error means that compass process choked on something and exited with an error. Try running the build with debug logs:

```
sencha -debug app build
```

This will get *very* verbose but may help you to pinpoint the problem.